# Query done in Python does not work when done in Golang. (MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, go

So, what I am trying to do is refactor some old code written in Python, making a new API in Go.
The query in Python is this one:

```
query = 'UPDATE info 'SET jsonField = JSON_REPLACE(jsonField, "$.content", null, "$.payload", null), 'field2 = %s ' WHERE Id = %s AND Id2 = %s AND Id3 = %s'
```

So, to work in Golang I changed it to:
`UPDATE info SET jsonField = JSON_REPLACE(jsonField, "$.content", null, "$.payload", null), field2 = ? WHERE Id = ? AND Id2 = ? AND Id3 = ?`

The code executing the query:

```
stmt, err = db.Prepare(query)
if err != nil {
    return opInfo, err
}
defer stmt.Close()
result, err := stmt.Exec(field2, Id, Id2, Id3)
if err != nil {
    return opInfo, err
}
fmt.Printf("\n query being executed: %s", query)
opInfo, err = result.RowsAffected()
fmt.Printf("\n modified Rows: %v", opInfo)
if err != nil {
    return opInfo, err
}
```

So, the problem? In Go the opInfo value is always 0, nothing changes but no errors.
I have checked that the values I am passing are different than the ones in the database and that the identifiers are right, "field2" it's a long string with special characters but that is why I am sending it like a blob.

Even if that were the problem, I tried separately to just modify the json in the database and to update "field2" to check if one of those were causing a problem. Failure in both attempts.

Am I missing something with the database driver from Go standard library?

Also there is no workaround to this, I am not changing from MySQL to a no-SQL DB.

In Python I was using:

```
cursor.execute(query, (field2, Id,Id2, Id3))
```

Stuck several weeks with this, please help.

Comment: can you share your table structure & what errors it throw while you try query through database cli?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE info SET jsonField = JSON_REPLACE(jsonField, %s, null, %s, null), field2 = ? WHERE Id = ? AND Id2 = ? AND Id3 = ?", content, payload)
```

Comment: That is the query in Python (hence the %s), in go I have it as `query` so everything is literal